# Make textbox width automatically changable in Stackpanel which is in Border, WPF

Tags: wpf, textbox

I wanted to put `Button` in `TextBox`, but as I found it's not possible so I decided to do something like this:

[image]

Xaml for this looks as shown below:

```
<Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0,10,0" 
            BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <TextBox BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Text="{Binding WaybillNumber}" 
                     Width="245"/>
            <Button  Content="*" Width="15" BorderThickness="1"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

The problem I have is that, when I resize my window (decreasing width) my `Button` dissapears:

[image]

I want it to behave as `DateTimePicker` does. I have tried many ways to make `TextBox` width auto adjustable ( `*` in width isn't correct input, `auto` decreases width of `TextBox`, I also tried to define style resource in `StackPanel` resources for `TextBox` width, but it doesn't work too), but Haven't found correct way yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `StackPanel` with a `Grid`:

```
<Border Margin="10,0,10,0" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Text="{Binding WaybillNumber}" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="*" Width="15" BorderThickness="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: I didn't know it :)

Answer (score 1):

use Grid instead of StackPanel. Setting fixed size (Width/Height) is not a good idea for adaptive layout. Grid will allow TextBox to stretch.

one option is to have separate columns for TextBox and Button:

```
<Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0,10,0" 
        BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Text="{Binding WaybillNumber}" />
        <Button Content="*" Grid.Column="1" Width="15" BorderThickness="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

alternatively place them in the same cell and let Button overlap TextBox (it will look like as a part of TextBox but can hide part of a long text):

```
<Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0,10,0" 
        BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Text="{Binding WaybillNumber}" />
        <Button Content="*" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2" Width="15" BorderThickness="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: meet [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).